# Android Studio Import Project Error

Tags: android

I internet download some example Android Project.
Import android studio but not working.
To give an example http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Android studio file -> Import Project
Project gie this error

```
Migrate Project to Gradle?
         This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system.
         More Information about migrating to Gradle
         Don't show this message again.
```

And this view

[image]

I use android studio 0.3.0

Comment: You need a build.gradle file, http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: Also looks like you dont have the support library in android studio.

Comment: @Joucks how I find build.gradle file ?

Comment: You need to create your own. You can have a look at the sample here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide. I'd advise you to create another fresh new project in Android Studio and see where the gradle files are generated and what they contain.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 1 requires the gradle-plugin 1.0.0.

Update your build.gradle file :

```
buildscript {
  ...
  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
  } 
}
```