# Github project import to Android Studio : Migrate Project to Gradle? This project does not use the Gradle build system

Tags: android, android-studio, github, gradle, importerror

First of all **This is not a duplicate of any of below questions**

[Migrate project to gradle error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26094169/6830731)

[Can't migrate project to Gradle in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21606504/6830731)

[This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34093459/6830731)

[Android Studio Import Project Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19816657/6830731)

Now let me talk about the problem. I've downloaded a zip file of GitHub project file to build on my laptop. **The name of GitHub project is  "VNCpp"**   As I'm not allowed to insert more than 2 links, I have given the project name so someone can search.

When I import this project into my android studio, it gives me this error : **"Migrate Project to Gradle? This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system"**

**Edit:** Android Studio has built in facility to import eclipse project and convert it into gradle build format. But in this case, it is not happening.

I'm getting 2 options while importing the project **1)Import from available sources and  2) Import from external model i.e gradle**

**When I select Import using external model**  it shows error like in this image:
[gradle path error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4LpM.png)

**And when I select Import from existing sources**  it creates some file system that doesn't have gradle structure. So I cannot edit and build the app on studio :
[File system without gradle structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGKqz.png)

What should I do now to properly import the project ?

Comment: The message is self explanatory. What do you want us to tell you? The migrate process describes that you have to import the `.project` of the Eclipse layout

Comment: And that second post cleanly explains the issue.  *The project thinks it's still a non-Gradle based project; it's not the presence of the build.gradle file that makes it Gradle-based, but it's how the project was set up in the first place.*

Comment: @cricket_007  Checkout the updated question with detailed information

Comment: For the first image, I think you have to actually download / install Gradle.

Comment: @cricket_007  It is already installed. It is working if i create a new project or work on my on going project etc. So there is no issue for installation of gradle.
Any other idea ?

Comment: Right, but the image shows you have not set the path to your Gradle installation

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem after reading **carefully** [the documentation(https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html).

1. Clone the project from GitHub
2. Close all Android Studio projects.
3. From the Android Studio welcome screen, click **Import Project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle etc)**.
4. Select the project folder **with the AndroidManifest.xml** file
5. Click ok.